# How to mock and spy on namespace in test suite?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to write tests for an Angular component that uses namespace. It compiles correctly, however I'm not quite sure how to mock or spy on namespace that's being used.

I've tried defining it in testing module providers, but that obviously won't work, since it's not being injected. Is there any other way to provide mock of namespace for unit test?

example stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-tyazbd

Comment: https://angular-testing-nbabcx.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the spying but rather the timing. The spy is created after the constructor was called and hence the method was already called before the spy was initialised.

One solution would be to call that function inside the ngOnInit which gets triggered with the first `fixture.detectChanges`

Have a look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-8audds

Comment: Well, that's actually really straightforward. Thank you!